Serving data to the Integration test
I'm designing currently the integration tests.
In the test object there are several entities and a quite complex data structure.
The application is itself a modular monolith for now, but targeting to be a microservice system (one day soon).
The system is far from ready, so many modules are not even designed.
My question is how to design the tests?

one approach should be to seed the data for the whole environment.
one should be to create them for each module/test class/test case

I would like to hear some opinion about how someone managed likewise situation and what was the experience with the solution.
Any idea is welcome.
I did in previous project to create data for each test case / test class where it was possible to make a common class without serious overhead.

This is a big time expense, but isolation ensured and easier to maintain them

I did met with project where data was seeded.

Any changes could break many tests, finding and fixing them was sometime a big problem and a lot of time

